# Error While Building using Maven

Tags: maven, build, mule

I am trying to build the Mule 2.2.8 jars using m2e eclipe plugin.
I am able to build a few jars successfully.
But later I am getting this exception.Can anyone help me with this.?

The error description is as below:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:1.4.3:bundle (default-bundle) on project mule-module-spring-config: Error calculating classpath for project MavenProject: org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:2.2.8 @ C:\Users\Rohit Chopra\Documents\Mule_2.2.8\modules\spring-config\pom.xml: error in opening zip file

The pom.xml snippet where maven bundle plugin is present is like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
                    <instructions>
                        <!-- Each module can override these defaults in their osgi.properties file -->
                        <_include>-osgi.properties</_include>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-DocURL>${pom.url}</Bundle-DocURL>
                        <!-- Non-OSGi manifest entries -->
                        <!-- This would work if this issue gets closed: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1832 -->
                        <!--Build-Date>${mvn.timestamp.yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss}</Build-Date-->
                        <!-- include repository revision from buildnumber plugin -->
                        <Build-Revision>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision>
                        <Build-Date>${timestamp}</Build-Date>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Can you please suggest some fix for removing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that you have a corrupted zip. Go to `<root>\Documents and Settings\<username>\.m2` and find org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin and remove it. Don't worry maven will download again.

I would also suggest to use Java 1.5 (IIRC that whats 2.2.8 required) and to put the source in a place without whitespaces in the path.

Comment: Hi Victor, I am facing similar issue while using jboss fuse. I removed `org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin`, but again when I run `mvn install` in my project, I again get same error. I have opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439660/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-felixmaven-bundle-plugin2-3-7. Any solution?